# Indexing a matrix with another matrix in R - index out of bounds

Tags: r, matrix

I am experiencing some strange behavior in R when trying to index a matrix with another matrix. I run into an error of subscript out of bounds with indexing with a 2 column matrix, but not with a four column matrix. See the following reproducible code. Any insight would be appreciated!

This

```
data <- matrix(rbinom(100, 1, .5), nrow = 10)
idx <- cbind(1:50, 51:100)
data[idx]
```

results in:

```
Error in data[idx] : subscript out of bounds
```

However

```
data[cbind(idx,idx)]
```

works.

My session info:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)
```

Comment: Well, `data` has 10 rows and 10 columns. `idx` has values that go up to 100. For example, the first row of `idx` is `1  51`, which would indicate the 1st row and 51st column. As `data` only has 10 columns, the 51st column is indeed out of bounds. If you instead use either (a) `idx = cbind(1:5, 6:10)` or (b) `data  = matrix(rbinom(100^2, 1. 0.5), nrow = 100)` then your code will work.

Comment: `idx` itself refers to the complete matrix, containing numbers 1 through 100. `data` is a 10 by 10 matrix so both subscript within 1 through 10 will not result in Error. However as soon as you start referring to numbers larger than 10, you will have subscript out of bounds error. Try `data[idx[2,2]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key insight as to why this is wrong isn't working is given in `?'['`:

> When indexing arrays by `[` a single argument `i` can be a  matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of `x`; the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of `i`.

and it is clear when the subscript out of bounds error arises; `data` doesn't have 50 rows and 100 columns.

What's happening in the second example the indexing matrix is just being treated as a vector because it has more columns than the matrix being indexed has dimensions, and is extracting elements `c(1:100, 1:100)` from `data`.

This is more easily see with

```
m <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
```

and indexing with `cbind(idx, idx)` gives

```
> m[cbind(idx,idx)]
  [1]   1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91   2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72
 [19]  82  92   3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83  93   4  14  24  34  44  54
 [37]  64  74  84  94   5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95   6  16  26  36
 [55]  46  56  66  76  86  96   7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97   8  18
 [73]  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98   9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99
 [91]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100   1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71
[109]  81  91   2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82  92   3  13  23  33  43  53
[127]  63  73  83  93   4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84  94   5  15  25  35
[145]  45  55  65  75  85  95   6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86  96   7  17
[163]  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97   8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98
[181]   9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80
[199]  90 100
```

which is the same as

```
m[c(idx[,1], idx[,2], idx[,1], idx[,2])]
```

or specifically,

```
m[c(1:50, 51:100, 1:50, 51:100)]
```